# Java JDBC - invalid character, put printing query and using it in SQLDeveloper works

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

rootID, FSA and others are all generated earlier in the code.

```
PreparedStatement getPotentialParents;

        sql = "SELECT UNIQUE_ID, NAME, ADDRESS_1, ADDRESS_2, POSTAL_CODE FROM "
                + "(SELECT * FROM("
                + "SELECT p.*, CONNECT_BY_ROOT UNIQUE_ID AS ROOT_ID "
                + "FROM UNIQUE_CLINIC p "
                + "START WITH PARENT_ID IS NULL "
                + "CONNECT BY PRIOR UNIQUE_ID = PARENT_ID "
                + "ORDER BY ROOT_ID))" + "WHERE ROOT_ID <> " + rootID + " "
                + "AND (FSA = '" + FSA + "' "
                + "OR NAME IN (" + others + ") "
                + "OR ADDRESS_1 IN (" + others + ") "
                + "OR ADDRESS_2 IN (" + others + "));";


        System.out.println(sql);


        getPotentialParents = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = getPotentialParents.executeQuery();
```

I get this error when this query is run, during execution: ORA-00911: invalid character

However, the printed SQL can be run on SQLDeveloper without errors:

```
SELECT UNIQUE_ID, NAME, ADDRESS_1, ADDRESS_2, POSTAL_CODE FROM (SELECT * FROM(SELECT p.*, CONNECT_BY_ROOT UNIQUE_ID AS ROOT_ID FROM UNIQUE_CLINIC p START WITH PARENT_ID IS NULL CONNECT BY PRIOR UNIQUE_ID = PARENT_ID ORDER BY ROOT_ID))
WHERE ROOT_ID <> 10548 AND (FSA = 'null' OR NAME IN ('BRENNAN''S AWESOME PHARMACY #1', '38 SOLUTIONS DR', 'NULLNULLNULL') OR ADDRESS_1 IN ('BRENNAN''S AWESOME PHARMACY #1', '38 SOLUTIONS DR', 'NULLNULLNULL') OR ADDRESS_2 IN ('BRENNAN''S AWESOME PHARMACY #1', '38 SOLUTIONS DR', 'NULLNULLNULL'));
```

I'm guessing JDBC is doing something to the SQL String before querying. Any idea what might be causing this? How can I get the actual query?

I've made some updates and it's still not working, giving me an invalid character. Once again, the printed sql can be run in sqldev with no problem.:

```
String FSA = rs.getString("FSA");
String rootID = String.valueOf((rs.getInt("ROOT_ID")));
String others = "'" + rs.getString("NAME").replace("'", "''") + "', '" + rs.getString("ADDRESS_1").replace("'", "''") + "', '" + rs.getString("ADDRESS_2").replace("'", "''") + "'";



    Statement getPotentialParents = connection.createStatement();

    sql = "SELECT UNIQUE_ID, NAME, ADDRESS_1, ADDRESS_2, POSTAL_CODE FROM "
            + "(SELECT * FROM("
            + "SELECT p.*, CONNECT_BY_ROOT UNIQUE_ID AS ROOT_ID "
            + "FROM UNIQUE_CLINIC p "
            + "START WITH PARENT_ID IS NULL "
            + "CONNECT BY PRIOR UNIQUE_ID = PARENT_ID "
            + "ORDER BY ROOT_ID)) " + "WHERE ROOT_ID <> " + rootID + " "
            + "AND (FSA = '" + FSA + "' "
            + "OR NAME IN (" + others + ") "
            + "OR ADDRESS_1 IN (" + others + ") "
            + "OR ADDRESS_2 IN (" + others + "));";


    System.out.println(sql);
    rs = getPotentialParents.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: it's very bad idea pass parameters to query like this. It is potential victim for sql injection. oracle recommends to use bind variables.

Comment: Remove the final `;` from the query string.

Comment: Are you sure the variable others contais the quotes?

Comment: String others = "'" + rs.getString("NAME").replace("'", "''") + "', '" + rs.getString("ADDRESS_1").replace("'", "''") + "', '" + rs.getString("ADDRESS_2").replace("'", "''") + "'";

Comment: That is another question, but are you sure you want to filter on FSA = 'null' ?

Comment: That's fine. I may modify it later, I just want to get this working.

Comment: Then I would also try to remove the trailing ';'.

Comment: Anyway - JDBC is definitely NOT modifying your query. I do not have Oracle instance at hand, therefore I cannot try it myself. Is Oracle not telling you which character it considers invalid?

Comment: After removing the trailing ';', I'm getting an invalid column name error. Again, when I just run the query in SQLDev, it works.

I'm going to try to get this to run with bind variables instead.

Answer (score 0):

You Can not  use PreparedStatement like this .
You have to use setString() methods to set values in qyery.
otherwise user CreateStatement instead of PreparedStatement

Statement getPotentialParents;

```
    sql = "SELECT UNIQUE_ID, NAME, ADDRESS_1, ADDRESS_2, POSTAL_CODE FROM "
            + "(SELECT * FROM("
            + "SELECT p.*, CONNECT_BY_ROOT UNIQUE_ID AS ROOT_ID "
            + "FROM UNIQUE_CLINIC p "
            + "START WITH PARENT_ID IS NULL "
            + "CONNECT BY PRIOR UNIQUE_ID = PARENT_ID "
            + "ORDER BY ROOT_ID))" + "WHERE ROOT_ID <> " + rootID + " "
            + "AND (FSA = '" + FSA + "' "
            + "OR NAME IN (" + others + ") "
            + "OR ADDRESS_1 IN (" + others + ") "
            + "OR ADDRESS_2 IN (" + others + "));";


    System.out.println(sql);


    getPotentialParents = connection.createStatement(sql);
    rs = getPotentialParents.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that I can't use a PreparedStatement like that? I've used it like that tons before. Is there a specific reason it isn't working in this case?

Comment: Also your code gives me the following error: "The method createStatement() in the type Connection is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: what is you connection code ??? is it direct from java.sql.Connection or overridden ???

Comment: You can also pass sql in executeQuery() as a parameter.

Comment: It's directly from java.sql.Connection. Maybe I'm using an old driver or something?

Comment: rs = getPotentialParents.executeQuery(sql);

Comment: What should I initialize getPotentialParents to, in that case?

Comment: yes you have to intialize it by DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);

Comment: I made an update in the main post, any idea why that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

First, check that this gives the expected results in Oracle:

```
VARIABLE rootid   NUMBER;
VARIABLE fsa      VARCHAR2(20);
VARIABLE name     VARCHAR2(20);
VARIABLE address1 VARCHAR2(200);
VARIABLE address2 VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN
  :rootid   := 10548;
  :fsa      := 'null';
  :name     := 'BRENNAN''S AWESOME PHARMACY #1';
  :address1 := '38 SOLUTIONS DR';
  :address2 := 'NULLNULLNULL';
END;
/

SELECT UNIQUE_ID,
       NAME,
       ADDRESS_1,
       ADDRESS_2,
       POSTAL_CODE
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT p.*,
           CONNECT_BY_ROOT UNIQUE_ID AS ROOT_ID
    FROM   UNIQUE_CLINIC p
    START WITH PARENT_ID IS NULL
    CONNECT BY PRIOR UNIQUE_ID = PARENT_ID
    ORDER BY ROOT_ID
  )
)
WHERE ROOT_ID <> :rootid
AND   (   FSA       = :fsa
      OR  NAME      IN ( :name, :address1, :address2 )
      OR  ADDRESS_1 IN ( :name, :address1, :address2 )
      OR  ADDRESS_2 IN ( :name, :address1, :address2 )
      );
```

If it does then you can just use the bind variables in Java:

(Note, you do not need the trailing `;` for the query.)

```
String sql = "SELECT UNIQUE_ID, NAME, ADDRESS_1, ADDRESS_2, POSTAL_CODE FROM ( SELECT * FROM ( SELECT p.*, CONNECT_BY_ROOT UNIQUE_ID AS ROOT_ID FROM UNIQUE_CLINIC p START WITH PARENT_ID IS NULL CONNECT BY PRIOR UNIQUE_ID = PARENT_ID ORDER BY ROOT_ID ) ) WHERE ROOT_ID <> :rootid AND ( FSA = :fsa OR NAME IN ( :name, :address1, :address2 ) OR ADDRESS_1 IN ( :name, :address1, :address2 ) OR ADDRESS_2 IN ( :name, :address1, :address2 ) )";

PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement( sql );
OraclePreparedStatement ops = (OraclePreparedStatement) ps;
ops.setStringAtName( "fsa", rs.getString("FSA") );
ops.setIntAtName( "rootid", rs.getInt("ROOT_ID") );
ops.setStringAtName( "name", rs.getString("NAME") );
ops.setStringAtName( "address1", rs.getString("ADDRESS_1") );
ops.setStringAtName( "address2", rs.getString("ADDRESS_2") );
ps.execute();
```